# JMeter Exception: org.apache.http.MalformedChunkCodingException

Tags: jmeter

I am running load testing scenario in `JMeter` for just 50 users over the VPN for my web application and I am getting the exception below. I have already set up `Implementation = HTTPClient4` under `HTTP Request Defaults` but the exception is still occurrs for a few transactions.

```
Response code: Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.MalformedChunkCodingException
Response message: Number of samples in transaction : 1, number of failing samples : 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The error most likely indicates an issue with either your [SUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_under_test) or underlying network transport or both. Check the logs on your application side and VPN server for any clues and report this to developers/network administrators.

If you are absolutely sure that your application behaves as expected you can try to switch JMeter's HTTP protocol implementation to `Java`. You can do this via [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults) - this way you can apply the desired configuration in only one place - the change will be propagated to all [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers in the HTTP Request Defaults [scope](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/UserManual/ScopingRules) (make sure that `Implementation` is blank for all the HTTP Request samplers as local changes override the global settings)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have checked by setting both Java and Blank implementation along with HTTPClient4 protocol but still no luck. I have already emailed my client to check network policies/administration to see the VPN and/or any issue at their end.